# Page Auto Refresh issue on PHP blade page scroll down in mobile devices

Tags: php, html, laravel, layout

I have been working on Laravel project and I found webpage working normal on desktop but not on mobile and tablets. When I open page in mobile devices and try to scroll down,at the same moment it auto refresh.

I haven't added any jQuery or Javascript file for autoload. Thanks for your time and help in advance.

I have added these things in head tag. I couldn't find any certain answers on the web. So, you can write down some relevant areas that I need to check to come up with the solution.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var baseUrl = "{{ URL::to('/') }}";
        var token = "{{{ Session::getToken() }}}";
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/home/scripts/jquery-1.12.2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/home/scripts/bootstrap_3.3.6.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery-validate.bootstrap-tooltip.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.validate.extra.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/home/scripts/scripts.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset("assets/home/scripts/html5lightbox/html5lightbox.js")}}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('blog/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-payment/jquery.payment.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/registration_validation.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/home/scripts/auth.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('assets/home/scripts/jquery.colorbox.js')}}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> function showImage(){$("#why_brandwood").toggle();}</script>

    <!-- cookie script -->
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/home/scripts/cookie.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Do you see the same behavior in different mobile browsers (chrome,ff, opera) ?

Comment: Yes. Auto refresh in all browsers in mobiles and tablets.

Comment: Finally, I found one line of code that basically do auto refresh when resizing.  Resizing happens when we open page in tablets or cellphones. 

This might help someone for debugging. By the way, thanks @PedroLobito for your help.

Comment: You can post an answer and accept it as the correct answer, that will help future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found one line of code in JavaScript that basically do auto refresh when resizing. Resizing happens when we open page in tablets or cellphones. This might help someone for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solution for me was to remove an autoscroll property within an html select tag.